# Why are these two methods that seem the same operate differently?

Tags: ruby, syntax

My method `exist­s_else` takes two parameters: `base` and `fallback`. If `base` is `nil`, it returns `fallback`. If it's not `nil`, it returns `base`. A call to `exist­s_else(true, false)` should return `true`.

If I use a standard looking `if`-statement, `true` is returned like I thought it would be:

```
def exist­s_else(bas­e, fallb­ack)
  unless base.­nil?
    base
  else
    fallb­ack
  end
end

a = true
exists_els­e( a, false­ )
# => true
```

If I use the inline implementation shown below, it returns `false`.

```
def exist­s_else(base, fallback)
  base unles­s base.nil­? else fallback
end

a = true
exists_els­e( a, false­ )
# => false
```

Why does does it return `false` in the inline implementation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your assertion that

```ruby
base unles­s base.nil­? else fallback
```

is supposed to be equivalent to the long-form `unless` statement is not true; in fact, you cannot use `else` inside a post condition. Ruby is interpreting the code as:

```ruby
def exist­s_else(base, fallback)
  base unles­s base.nil­?
else fallback
end
```

If you type this (or the version without the newline, as in your question) into IRB, Ruby gives the following warning:

```
warning: else without rescue is useless
```

That is to say, Ruby is trying to interpret the `else` as part of exception handling code, as in

```ruby
def exists_else(base, fallback)
  base unless base.nil
rescue ArgumentError => e
  # code to handle ArgumentError here
else
  # code to handle other exceptions here
end
```

Comment: Better answer than mine. More detail.

Answer (score 4):

You can not use an `else` statement when you're trying to do it in one line. When an `else` is necessary you must use the extended version.

Ruby thinks that the `else` in this case is related to error handling. You have to stick to your initial `unless-end` method.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer this syntax to evaluate true/false checks:

```
condition(s) ? true_value : false_value
```

In your case, it would look like:

```
def exists_else(base, fallback)
  base.nil? ? fallback : base
end

a = true
puts exists_else(a, false)  # => true
```